# On proving that a set is arc connected.

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove that the set

$$A =\{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 \ | \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1 , \ |x+y+z| \le \sqrt{3}/ 2 \}$$

Is arc-connected.

So I took as an arc between any two points $x_1, x_2$ in $A$ the function $f(t) = tx_1 + (1-t) x_2 $.

I could see that for any $t$ the $f(t)$ would satisfy the first condition because:

$$|| tx_1 + (1-t) x_2 || \le t ||x_1 || + (1-t) ||x_2 || \le 1$$

for any $t$.

I tried the second condition coordinate wise but was unsuccessful, I'm not sure how to do this.

How could I do?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ or $\leq 1$?

Comment: @A.P. thanks edited.

Comment: I think it's easier to initially go about this by thinking geometrically. Imagine the set $A:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\colon |x+y+z|\le\sqrt{3}/2\}$. We know that $A$ is trapped between the two planes defined by $x+y+z=\sqrt{3}/2$ and $x+y+z=-\sqrt{3}/2$. You should convince yourself that the part of the unit sphere sandwiched by these two planes is contained in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_i,y_i,z_i) \in A$ for $i=1,2$ and \begin{align}f(t) &= (1-t)(x_1,y_1,z_1) + t(x_2,y_2,z_2) \\&= ((1-t)x_1 + tx_2,(1-t)y_1 + ty_2,(1-t)z_1 + tz_2)\end{align} for $t \in [0,1]$.

Then $$\begin{align}\lvert (1-t)x_1 + tx_2 + (1-t)y_1 + ty_2 + (1-t)z_1 + tz_2\rvert &= \lvert (1-t)(x_1 + y_1 + z_1) + t(x_2+y_2+z_2)\rvert\\&\leq (1-t)\lvert x_1 + y_1 + z_1\rvert + t\lvert x_2 + y_2 + z_2 \rvert \\ &\leq (1-t)\sqrt{3}/2 + t\sqrt{3}/2 \\ &= \sqrt{3}/2,\end{align}$$
so that $f(t)$ also satisfies the second condition.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Definition:*** A subset $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is called *convex* if for every two points $x,y \in C$ we have $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in C$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$, i.e. if the line from $x$ and $y$ lies in $C$.

You have already noticed that convex sets are arc-connected. So we want to show that $A$ is convex.

We have $A = A_1 \cap A_2$ for
\begin{align*}
 A_1 &= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1\}, \\
 A_2 &=
  \left\{
   (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \,\middle|\, |x+y+z| \leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
  \right\}.
\end{align*}
It is easy to see that the intersection of convex sets is again convex, so it sufficies to show that both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are convex. You have already shown that $A_1$ is, so we only need to do so for $A_2$.

Now the closed intervall $I = [-\sqrt{3}/2, \sqrt{3}/2] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is convex, and for the linear map $f \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y,z) = x+y+z$ we have $A_2 = f^{-1}(I)$. Now we just observe the following:

> ***Lemma:*** If $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is convex and $g \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear then $f^{-1}(C) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is also convex.
>
> *Proof:* For all $x,y \in g^{-1}(C)$ we have $g(x),g(y) \in C$ and thus for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$
>   $$
>  g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y)
>  = \lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda) g(y) \in C,
> $$
>   and therefore $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y \in g^{-1}(C)$.